# Return multidimensional vector from function for use in main, how to use correctly?

Tags: c++, function, vector, return

I've found that using a vector is the best way to achieve what I need to do, however I now need some clarification.

I need to generate a multidimensional array within a function in an external CPP, then make this available within main.

main.cpp

```
// include vector, using namespace etc.
function(2, 4);

// how to access vector elements here - vectorname[2][4]->classvar;  ?
```

vectors.cpp

```
void function(value1, value2){
// class def
int value1 = value1;
int value2 = value2;
 vector<int>(value1)<vector<Class>(value2) vectorname>; // incorrect syntax? or new * vector ?

return vectorname; // ?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax with `vector` requires a little getting used to. A 2D vector of `int` looks like this:

```
vector<vector<int> > myVector;
```

If you would like to set specific dimensions, use constructors that take size:

```
vector<vector<int> > myVector(10, vector<int>(5));
```

This produces a `10x5` vector of zeros. You can do this

```
vector<vector<int> > myVector(10, vector<int>(5, -1));
```

to provide initial values for your elements (`-1` in this case).

As a rule of thumb, you want your vectors passed by reference and returned by value.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know the size the vector needs to be until it's been created in the function, so do I need to define this in main without default values, and pass it in by reference?

Comment: @JackFarrow You can certainly do that. You could also not initialize it in `main` at all, and return it by value: `vector<vector<int> > myVect = function(4, 6);`

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what is happening in the above code? I assume this is defining a vector (like a int, called myVect), and assinging it to the vector values created in the function? Is this best performance wise?

Comment: @JackFarrow That is precisely what happens. It is not the best performance wise (at least, not yet), but it is easier to get right. C++11 compilers with "move constructor" semantic should be able to get this to perform at least as well as passing a reference. If your matrix is small, you wouldn't notice the cost of the copy; if it is big (thousands of entries), then go with your original pass by reference approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a multi-dimensional vector of your class, it should be:

```
vector<vector<Class> > vectorname;
return vectorname;
```

The signature of the function should be:

```
vector<vector<Class> > function(value1, value2)
```

and the following:

```
int value1 = value1;
int value2 = value2;
```

is pointless.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So where does the signature need to go, inside main or inside the function? If inside main how do I assign values to the vector within the function? In the normal way? Thanks.

Comment: @JackFarrow the signature goes wherever you declare the function, and in the definition. You change the contents of the vector with `push_back` or you can preallocate the memory and use `[][]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a multidimensional vector like this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > v;
```

You can also use typedef to make code easier to follow:

```
typedef std::vector<int> int_vector;
typedef std::vector<int_vector> int_matrix;
```

When writing like in the first example, you should avoid writing the closing angle brackets one after the other to avoid the compiler confuse it with the `>>` operator.

You should also avoid returning objects like this from a function because this operation involves copying the whole vector. Instead, you can pass a vector by reference for example:

```
void process(int_matrix& m)
{
    // m.push_back(...)
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int_matrix m;

    // Initialize m here.
    // ...

    // Call your methods.
    process(m);

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

You can structure your code like this:

```
// int_matrix.hpp

#ifndef _INT_MATRIX_HPP
#define _INT_MATRIX_HPP

#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> int_vector;
typedef std::vector<int_vector> int_matrix;

extern void process(int_matrix& m);

#endif // ~_INT_MATRIX_HPP
```

.

```
// int_matrix.cpp

#include "int_matrix.hpp"

void process(int_matrix& m)
{
    m.clear();
    // ...
}
```

.

```
// main.cpp

#include "int_matrix.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int_matrix m1;
    int_matrix m2;

    // ...

    process(m1);
    process(m2);

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess the next question is how to correctly forward declare this vector, as the function will be external to main? Can this even be done?!

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer for an example of how you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <vector>
  3 using namespace std;
  4 
  5 class Test {
  6 public:
  7     Test()
  8     {
  9         cout << "Test()" << endl;
 10     }
 11     ~Test()
 12     {
 13         cout << "~Test()" << endl;
 14     }
 15 };
 16 typedef Test classvar_t;
 17 typedef vector<classvar_t> d2_t;
 18 typedef vector<d2_t > md_vector_t;
 19 md_vector_t foo(int value1, int value2)
 20 {
 21     return md_vector_t(value1, d2_t(value2));
 22 }
 23 
 24 int main()
 25 {
 26     md_vector_t v = foo(3, 4);
 27     cout << "--------" << endl;
 28     return 0;
 29 }
```

Comment: You can, but why on earth would you, when it leads to memory leaks?

Comment: Yes, the past one will lead memory leaks, if you generated it and didn't delete it.I have make it better now.