# How to: return multidimensional vector (Matrix) from function - using header

Tags: c++, matrix, return

I'd like to read a matrix from cin, using a function, then return matrix back to main.

Here's my code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include "mymath.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

vector<vector<double>> matrix_read();

Sleep(60000);
return 0;
}
```

**mymath.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MYMATH_H
#define MYMATH_H
vector<vector<double>> matrix_read();
#endif
```

**mymath.cpp**

```
#include "mymath.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


vector<vector<double>> matrix_read() {

        cout << "How big is the quadratic matrix A?\n";
        int n;
        //row&column size A
        cin >> n;
        vector<vector<double>> A(n, vector<double>(n));
        //fill matrix A
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                cin >> A[i][j];
            }
        }
        //control matrix A:
        cout << "Please be sure this is the correct Matrix A: \n";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                cout << A[i][j] << " ";
            }
        cout << endl;
        }
return A;
}
```

for reference:
[Return multidimensional vector from function for use in main, how to use correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193136/return-multidimensional-vector-from-function-for-use-in-main-how-to-use-correct)

[Error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9pWr.jpg)

*What is my error?*

The error list implies there's a major mistake. Thank you for your help. Please be gentle, newbie here.

Comment: `>>` is an operator in C++, put a space in your variable and function definitions.

Comment: In the `mymath.h` header file, what is `vector`? Think about that for a little while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to prefix `vector` with `std::vector` in the header, if you did not have `using namespace std;` before the include directive. Anyway, it's good practice to have `std::` in the header.
2. In main, it should be

   ```
   int main(){

       vector<vector<double>> matrix = matrix_read();

       Sleep(60000);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

i.e. you set the object `matrix` to the return value of the function. Otherwise, you would define another prototype for `matrix_read` in the main function.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. This worked fine. I will post the now working code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maximilian Matthé was right. Here's the working code:

**mymath.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix_read();
```

**mymath.cpp**

```
#include "mymath.h"


std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix_read() {

std::cout << "How big is the quadratic matrix A?\n";
int n;
//row&column size A
std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> A(n, std::vector<double>(n));

        //fill matrix A
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                std::cout << "Please enter the value for A" << "[" << i + 1 << "]" << "[" << j + 1 << "]\n";
                std::cin >> A[i][j];
            }
        }
        //control matrix A:
        std::cout << "Please be sure this is the correct Matrix A: \n\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            std::cout << A[i][j] << " ";
            }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        }
return A;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>

    #include "mymath.h"

    int main() {

        std::vector<std::vector<double>> A = matrix_read();

    Sleep(60000);
    return 0;
    }
```